# Confusing behaviour when streaming exec command outputs from c programs and shell scripts

Tags: c, linux, go

I wrote a test program to analyse the behaviour of a piece of code that caused a bug today, to understand its behaviour better. The opposite happend.

This is the test program. It should execute a testcommand and stream the commands output to stdout.

```golang
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd1 := exec.Command("./testcommands/testcommand.sh")
    execCmd(cmd1)
    cmd2 := exec.Command("./testcommands/testcommand")
    execCmd(cmd2)
}

func execCmd(cmd *exec.Cmd) {
    stderr, _ := cmd.StderrPipe()
    stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    multi := io.MultiReader(stdout, stderr)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(multi)
    cmd.Start()
    for scanner.Scan() {
        m := scanner.Text()
        fmt.Println(m)
    }
    cmd.Wait()
}
```

The two testcommands called do basically the same. One is implemented in bash

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in `seq 1 10` ; do 
    echo "run $i"
    sleep 1
done
```

The other one in C

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        printf("run %d\n", i);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the shell script does get streamed (1 line per second), however the output of the c program only arrives after the program is finished completely (10 lines at once after 10 seconds).

This goes way over my head. I'm not even sure if this is working as intended and i'm just missing something, or if i should open a bug report - and if so, i'm not even sure if it'll be for bash, golang or c. Or maybe it's some linux thing i don't know about.

Comment: bash will flush stdout after each command. The c program will buffer writes, so needs an explicit flush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `stdout` (to which `printf` writes) is connected to a terminal, then `stdout` will be line-buffered and output will be flushed (actually written) on each newline.

But when `stdout` is not connected to a terminal, like for example it's used for redirection or a pipe, then it's *fully* buffered. Fully buffered means the output only will be written when the buffer becomes full (unlikely in your small example) or when explicitly flushed (for example with `fflush(stdout)`).

What the Go `exec` functionality probably does is to create *pipes* for the programs input and output.

To solve your problem, your C program needs to call `fflush` after each `printf` call:

```
printf("run %d\n", i);
fflush(stdout);
```

Comment: Alternatively, the program could call any appropriate function of the `setbuf(3)` family before performing any I/O on its stdout.

Comment: Is there a way to force the buffer to get flushed from the calling go program?

Comment: @COMMANDERCAPSLOCK No, once you've started the program it runs independently and with its own buffers.

Comment: The *FILE object with variable name “stdout” is what encapsulates the buffering logic, and printf uses that for writing its output. The underlying file descriptor 1, which often called by the same name, does not have buffering on it (eg if you did write(1, “hello\n”, 6) you would always get six bytes of output on the other end of the file descriptor, no matter if it’s a terminal or not).

Comment: @commander-capslock, "it depends": if you know you're dealing with a program making use of those `FILE*` streams provided by `libc`, you can wrap its call in an invocation of [`stdbuf`](https://manpages.debian.org/1/stdbuf). Of course, that won't work in two cases: 1) the program itself messes with its own buffering, programmatically; 2) it does not rely on that libc feature to output or consume data—for instance, Go programs do not.